# rpart package not showing complete plot

Tags: r, rpart

I am using Rpart for first time but not able to understand few things:

```
 str(X1)
```

> 'data.frame':   7329 obs. of  4 variables:
>        $ totalordered               : num  34 800 36 254 564 ...
>        $ number_of_orders           : int  1 4 1 2 4 1 2 1 1 1 ...
>        $ custom_field_classification: Factor w/ 5 levels "Education: Educator/Student",..: 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 4 3 ...
>        $ CLTV                       : int  0 363 0 5 114 0 119 0 0 0 ...

```
>model1 <- rpart(custom_field_classification ~.,data=X1,method="class")
>model1
```

> n= 7329 
>        node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
>             * denotes terminal node
>
> ```
> 1) root 7329 4591 Education: Educator/Student (0.37 0.24 0.12 0.23 0.043)  
>   2) totalordered< 104.715 4043 1898 Education: Educator/Student (0.53 0.15 0.092 0.19 0.038) *
>   3) totalordered>=104.715 3286 2151 Education: K-12 (0.18 0.35 0.15 0.27 0.051) *
> ```

```
>summary(model1)

Call:
rpart(formula = custom_field_classification ~ ., data = X1, method = "class")
  n= 7329 

         CP nsplit rel error    xerror        xstd
1 0.1180571      0 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.009020710
2 0.0100000      1 0.8819429 0.8832498 0.009270542

Variable importance
    totalordered number_of_orders             CLTV 
              54               26               20 

Node number 1: 7329 observations,    complexity param=0.1180571
  predicted class=Education: Educator/Student  expected loss=0.6264156  P(node) =1
    class counts:  2738  1724   866  1683   318
   probabilities: 0.374 0.235 0.118 0.230 0.043 
  left son=2 (4043 obs) right son=3 (3286 obs)
  Primary splits:
      totalordered     < 104.715 to the left,  improve=312.20560, (0 missing)
      number_of_orders < 2.5     to the left,  improve= 93.21119, (0 missing)
      CLTV             < 0.5     to the left,  improve= 63.99499, (0 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      number_of_orders < 1.5     to the left,  agree=0.773, adj=0.493, (0 split)
      CLTV             < 0.5     to the left,  agree=0.718, adj=0.370, (0 split)

Node number 2: 4043 observations
  predicted class=Education: Educator/Student  expected loss=0.4694534  P(node) =0.5516442
    class counts:  2145   589   370   787   152
   probabilities: 0.531 0.146 0.092 0.195 0.038 

Node number 3: 3286 observations
  predicted class=Education: K-12              expected loss=0.6545953  P(node) =0.4483558
    class counts:   593  1135   496   896   166
   probabilities: 0.180 0.345 0.151 0.273 0.051
```

1. Why all my factors levels are not showing? (I have 5 levels and it is showing only two?)
2. Why I can only see total ordered but not the rest of the parameters ? like number of orders ,CLTV?

[image: R plot looks like this]

Comment: change your cp value for the rpart?

Comment: @AdamQuek how to do that? Any help is appreciated..learning R

Comment: [Explanation for complexity parameter](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/117909/112179). Change cp value with [rpart control](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/rpart.control.html). See example in [rpart documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/rpart/html/rpart.html)

Comment: @AdamQuek the cp doesn't actually change the output from summary(rpart_obejct); how do I get it to plot the primary splits?